# Child table not updating during Parent update using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have two tables with one to many relationship.

`TableA`, properties and `ICollectionof TableB` items

`TableB` with properties

In the EF,

```
TableAobjectref.ICollection<TableB>ref.Add(new tableBobject)

_tableAservice.Update(tableA).
```

this only updating tableA not tableB. Any advice?

This is my update method in generic repository, I can see its updating parent table but not child. How ever have added child to parent in the update operation shouldn't that sufficent to update child table?

```
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    dbset.Attach(entity);
    dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```